# Which is best sencha or Phonegap to communicate with restful web services,parse the json data and then show it to the user?

Tags: android, json, cordova, sencha-touch

I need to build a mobile application which should communicate with the restful web services,parse the json data coming from it and then render it to the user.I need to create a hybrid app, so which is better in this context,is it Phonegap or is it sencha?

Answer (score 0):

Sencha provides api to do Ajax calls. You can do the same using phonegap + jquery.
So it's easy with both. I do prefer phonegap but it's just a personal opinion.

Answer (score 0):

I use JQuery within a Phonegap app for this. Phonegap is designed to abstract away your interaction with mobile device APIs rather than server communication and JSON parsing.

Using JQuery you can just use standard AJAX calls and JSON.parse/JSON.stringify for JSON parsing.

```
this.refreshPreferences = function(inBackground){
    console.log("Refreshing preferences");
    var self = this;
    $.ajax({
      url: getBaseUrl()+"/prefs/index.jsonp",
      dataType: "jsonp",
      crossDomain: true,
      timeout: 2500,
      data: {
        auth_token: storage.getItem('auth_token')
      }
    })
    .done( function ( response ) {
      storage.setItem(LS_PREFERENCES_KEY,JSON.stringify(response));         
    })
    .fail( function (){
      console.log("Unable to communicate with server");
    })
};
```